# Laravel 5.4 Backpack can't delete item, returns "403 Forbidden" error

Tags: laravel, apache2, laravel-backpack

I was working on an admin panel using backpack for Laravel. When I want to delete some item by hitting the delete button, I get a *Not Deleted* error - see screenshots.

[image]

[image]

It looks like the 403 and 405 errors that can occur when the `CRUD::resource()` or `Route::resource` method are used but the server (apache in my case) does not allow them on dynamic resources - whatever that means in detail ...

Is there a way to enable these methods on Apache?

I got it working, but I would like to use the default HTTP methods.

**Quick Fix**

I was able to fix this problem by duplicating and modifying the `list.blade.php` CRUD view of backpack.

1. Duplicate the view `vendor/backpack/crud/src/resources/views/list.blade.php` and move it to `resources/views/vendor/backpack/crud/list.blade.php`
2. Modify the AJAX request defined on line 271.

   ```
    if (confirm("{{ trans('backpack::crud.delete_confirm') }}") == true) {
         $.ajax({
             url: delete_url,
             type: 'POST', // change from DELETE to POST
             data: { // "spoof" the HTTP verb "DELETE"
               "_method": "DELETE"
             },
   ```

Answer (score 1):

laravel/framework: 5.8.2
backpack/crud: 3.6

vendor/backpack/crud/src/resources/views/buttons/delete.blade.php
replace this code:
`type: 'DELETE',`

with this lines:

```
type: 'POST',
data: {
      "_method": "DELETE"
},
```

Answer (score -1):

you should check Access in you controller

```
$this->crud->allowAccess(['delete']);
```

i think you no necessary so complex like this.
when you install backpack,you shoudld run like

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Backpack\Base\BaseServiceProvider" #publishes configs, langs, views and AdminLTE files
```

it will auto copy file to right place